ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' in python in visual studio code in windows 10, and mysql-connector-python is properly installed
My python code was running normally in vs code on Windows and then out of the blue.
It started giving this error:

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'" when I try to import mysql.connector.

I did not touch the code. The error came out of nowhere.
I am using python 3.11.8 and the version of mysql-connector-python is 8.0.25
I already tried the solutions available here, like checking if mysql connector is installed or uninstalling and installing the library again but it is not working for me.
